# Warning: Unexpected default export of anonymous function. Why is default export of an anonymous function unexpected

Tags: javascript, import, next.js, export, warnings

I am using Nextjs and I got this warning:

> Nextjs Warning: Unexpected default export of anonymous function.

Why is default export of an anonymous function unexpected? Why should the function be named?

Comment: That looks like a linting warning which can probably be disabled. However, it's good practice to name your default export functions as it makes debugging easier (makes it easier to find the function/module where the error comes from).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I was wondering what the benefit is. Now I know. Thank you.